# Variable not found while using facet_wrap in r

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

this is my data:

```
> head(datos, 10)
   t_ventas        año     n
1    Grande 2012-03-28  2617
2   Mediana 2012-03-28  6281
3     Micro 2012-03-28 37641
4   Pequeña 2012-03-28 16676
5    Grande 2013-03-28  2833
6   Mediana 2013-03-28  6822
7     Micro 2013-03-28 40280
8   Pequeña 2013-03-28 17858
```

And I am trying to use this command ggplot to compute a graph

```
ggplot(datos) +
 aes(x = `Año`, y = n, fill = t_ventas, colour = t_ventas) +
 geom_line(size = 1L) +
 scale_fill_hue() +
 scale_color_hue() +
 labs(x = "3", y = "4", subtitle = "1", caption = "2") +
 theme_light() +
 theme(legend.position = "none") +
 facet_wrap(vars(t_ventas), scales = "free")
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error in eval(variables_names, envir = envir, enclos = baseenv()) : 
  object 't_ventas' not found
```

I think it gotta do something with the `facet_wrap` function?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As R is indicating, it can't find an object called "t_ventas." It is attempting to evaluate that as a literal variable name. Assuming you want to facet wrap around the name of the column in your dataset, all you should need to do is wrap it in quotes, i.e. `facet_wrap("t_ventas")`. If you want to have more than one column, you can put a character vector in its place.

Comment: So the `vars(t_ventas)` was wrong? It did worked, but i used `esquisse` to generate that ggplot code.  Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that will work because t_ventas isn't defined. I'm not familiar with the `esquisse` package though. Maybe it assumes you are attaching the dataset and that makes it work?

Comment: It's an add in that generates the ggplot code. And you just select the variables you want.